# Como generar una lista de urls bajo cierta condicion?

Tags: python, url

Necesito crear una lista de urls la cual vaya variando el numero de la fecha por ejemplo : este es un url de mi lista https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230211.xls (LA CUAL CORRESPONDE A UN ARCHIVO DEL DIA 02/11) , necesito que varian los numeros que dejare la XX y la NN por ejemplo : https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/NN/RIO23NNXX.xls (CONSIDERAR QUE NN ES EL MES Y XX EL DIA ) .

Tengo el siguiente codigo el cual lo hace de manera manual de la fecha 02/11 hasta 02/20:

```
import os
import requests
from time import time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


def url_response(url):
    
    nombre, url = url
    path = f"RIO/{nombre}.xls"
    #path, url = url
    r = requests.get(url, stream = True)
 
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
 
        for ch in r:
            f.write(ch)

urls = [("RIO230211", "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230211.xls"),
("RIO230212", "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230212.xls"),("RIO230213", "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230213.xls"),("RIO230214", "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230214.xls"),("RIO230215", "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230215.xls"),("RIO230216", "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230216.xls"),("RIO230217", "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230217.xls"),("RIO230218", "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230218.xls"),("RIO230219", "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230219.xls"),("RIO230220", "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230220.xls"),("RIO230221", "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230221.xls")]

ThreadPool(12).imap_unordered(url_response, urls)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una función que tome como parámetros el día inicial y los la cantidad de días.

Aquí un ejemplo de lo que digo:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def generar_urls(fecha_inicio:datetime, dias) -> list:
    urls = []
    formato_url = "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/{}/{}/{}.xls"

    for dia in range(dias):
        fecha_inicio += timedelta(days=1)
        year, month, day = fecha_inicio.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").split("-")
        codigo = f"RIO{year[-2:]}{month}{day}"
        urls.append((codigo, formato_url.format(year, month, codigo)))
    return urls
```

Primero importamos `datetime` para poder usar `datetime` para el manejo de la fecha y `timedelta` para poder hacer operaciones con la fecha, cómo puede ser el sumar días.

La función consiste en un ciclo `for` en cada iteración del ciclo se va sumando `1` día a la fecha inicial y así hasta haber cumplido con el número de días que se añadirán.

Luego se convierte la fecha (objeto datetime) a un string para poder separarlo por partes y obtener el año, mes y día. Otra forma de obtener esos datos es accediendo a sus atributos `.year`, `.month`, `.day`

Una vez teniendo esos datos ya podemos armar el código y la url a la que se hará la petición, luego agregamos eso a la lista en forma de tupla. Al finalizar todo se retorna la lista generada.

```
liat_urls = generar_urls(datetime.strptime("2023-02-10", "%Y-%m-%d"), 19)
```

Si tienes preguntas puedes dejarlas en los comentarios :D

Comment: Todo muy bien solo que la url que entrega es https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/11/RIO230211.xls y deberia ser https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230211.xls

Comment: Y tengo otro porblema, para cuando pongo mas de 19 items sobre pasa el mes (31 dias) como hago para que cambie de mes sin tener que hacer esta linea de codigo para los 12 meses?

Comment: Para el primer error, solo es confusión mía, agregué el día a la url, solo es cuestión de quitarla y para lo segundo pues no hay problema ya que al usar `timedelta` y `datetime` este hace todo el manejo necesario, si te pasas del mes automaticamente se pasará al siguiente mes

Comment: Muchas gracias , solucionaste todos mis problemas. Otra pequeña duda sobre este codigo , si quisiera que enves de que empezara a generar la lista de codigo desde el dia 2023-01-01 enves de 2023-02-11 que deberia cambiar?

Comment: Ya lo corregi , no te preocupes

Comment: tengo la siguiente duda, si quiero que se imprima hasta le fecha actual por ejemplo utilizando date.today() o algo por el estilo para que cada dia que pase descargue hasta la fecha actual y no asi indicarle cuantas Url quiero que cree. De antemano gracias

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer por ahora es sacar la diferencia de días. Igual espérame un rato y edito la respuesta agregando lo que me dices

Comment: ya lo solucione. Gracias

Comment: Tengo el siguiente problema , la url que estaba creando paso de ser : https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230220.xls , a https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230220-9.xls , (se le agrega el guion y un numero aleatorio , como podria hacer esto que tome el guion y reconozca cualquier numero que venga despues )

Comment: Solo modifica la variable `formato_url` agrega el guión y otro campo para colocar el número aleatorio. Este lo puedes generar usando la librería `random`

Comment: El problema es que ese numero random necesito saberlo, me explico : Esta lista que estoy creando es para descargargar estos urls , este url puede salir con -7 o -8 o -X, necestito dejar la url para que solo lea los archivos que tienen el guion (respetando lo que hicimos antes de lo de las fechas )

Comment: Las urls que estamos creando son de esta pagina: https://www.coordinador.cl/operacion/documentos/registro-de-instrucciones-de-operacion-rio/ , si seleccionas un dia por ejemplo 20.02.2023 y copias el vinculo del archivo a descargar sale con un -9 y asi pasa con los demas vinculos (- y numero aleatorio) como podria hacer esto?

Comment: Recomiendo que formules otra pregunta con todos los detalles para poder ayudarte. Los comentarios no son para discutir sobre otros problemas. Además, otras personas también podrán ver tu pregunta y ofrecer otras soluciones

Comment: Enseguida lo hago , muchas gracias

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/584142/como-identificar-una-url-con-python  , @Christian , no se si esta bien formulada mi pregunta